# Javascript, detect if the textbox has focus?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser

I'm upgrading a script to make it crosss browser. The current code I have is as follows.

```
function testFocus(){   
    var testSelection = document.getElementById('chattext').contentWindow.
                  window.document.selection.createRange().parentElement();

    while (testSelection)
    {
        if (testSelection.id == "chatContent") {
            return true;
        }
        testSelection = testSelection.parentElement;
    }
    return false; 
}
```

However the following code no longer works in modern browsers. Presently the code above has to have text selected. Where it just needs to check that the textbox has focus. The function is used as a check before text is added by a button / javascript.

Comment: In addition to post of _Alex C_ you can read about `document.activeElement` in MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.activeElement and MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533065%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strikes me that you could use an event listener to set a variable.  The only problem being that IE uses `attachEvent(event, callback)` instead of `addEventListner` so you've actually got to add the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ChatHasFocus = false;
  var ts = document.getElementById('chattext');
  function setFocus()  {ChatHasFocus = true;}
  function setNoFocus(){ChatHasFocus = false;}
  if (ts.addEventListener != undefined) { 
      ts.addEventListener('focus', setFocus, false);
      ts.addEventListener('blur', setNoFocus, false);
  } else if (ts.attachEvent != undefined) {
      ts.attachEvent('onfocus', setFocus);
      ts.attachEvent('onblur', setNoFocus);
  } else {
      ts.onmouseover = setFocus;
      ts.onmouseout = setNoFocus;
  }
</script>
```

**edit** - I've added script tags to show you how it adds to your document.  I've tested in firefox and chrome and it seems to work, but getting an IE sandbox together might be a little more difficult for me.  I'm sure there's something little that I'm missing there - i'll take a look.

**edit2** i made a mistake with the IE code.  tuns out you don't put quotes around `'undefined'` I've fixed the code above to reflect an answer that is tested and wotkign in firefox, chrome and IE6.  I don't have any other IEs  to test in.

Comment: This causes an error Error: Unable to get value of the property 'attachEvent': object is null or undefined, in IE

Comment: sorry - I added `!= 'undefined'`  which should be safer

Comment: Where do I put the code? I tried it in the testFocus but it always returns ChatHasFocus as false.

Comment: try putting it underneath "test focus"   ChatHasFocus is essentially a global boolean, and the two events happen then you click on the chatbox and click off again.  It will all happen "automatically" when you load the page.  It is not part of the testFocus function.

Comment: I'm getting a new error Unable to get value of the property 'addEventListener': object is null or undefined.. I've tried without, RE you second example, but that didn't work either.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3371/discussion-between-alex-c-and-jules)